# How to append SSL Origin Certificate with CloudFlare's Root Certificate?

Tags: security, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

I was going through [this tutorial](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/224985668-Installing-CloudFlare-Origin-CA-on-cPanel) where mentioned the process of "Installing CloudFlare Origin CA on cPanel".

Everything was fine, except "Append CloudFlare's Root Certificate".

I had received .pem key from [Cloudflare Support](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218689638-What-are-the-root-certificate-authorities-CAs-used-with-CloudFlare-Origin-CA-) where mentioned as well "*you will need to append the appropriate root below to your .pem file.*"

I have CloudFlare Origin CA — RSA Root.

I need help on Italic part. **How to just append?**. Please elaborate with description, it will help others too.

Answer (score 2):

You literally just need to to the file; at the very end, with a line break after the last certificate.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
(Your Origin CA certificate) 
-----END CERTIFICATE----- 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
(CloudFlare's Root certificate) 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

This will form an SSL Certificate Trust Chain whereby the certificate can be validated with [CloudFlare's Root Certificate](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218689638-What-are-the-root-certificate-authorities-CAs-used-with-CloudFlare-Origin-CA-). You can then [use this certificate with your webserver](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218408028-How-to-install-an-Origin-CA-Certificate-Other-) to utilise Full (Strict) SSL mode in CloudFlare.

Comment: Well, at least doing that did not produce any more errors than I had previously, so that is a plus.  Now I get:

ec2-user # service nginx reload
 * Checking nginx' configuration ...
nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, host not found in OCSP responder "ocsp.cloudflare.com/origin_ca"                                     [ ok ]
 * Refreshing nginx' configuration ...